# Функциональный язык, объеденяющий качество синтаксиса Haskell и качество технологии Erlang

Tags: haskell, erlang

Есть ли такой (хотя бы в разработке)?

Качество синтаксиса Хаскела, чем нравится, пояснять не буду — он прекрасен. В технологии Эрланга же сильная сторона — это **реализация** параллельных вычислений (легкие процессы) и OTP, но очень уродливый синтакс. Киньте камень, если не так.

Comment: А в чём вопрос?

Comment: есть ли такой? (хотя бы в разработке)

Comment: В эпоху пирамид (финансовых) Милявская с Цекало рекламировали фин. фирму Хопёр

    -- Хопёр-инвест -- отличная компания.
    -- От других.

Отличная технология Erlang с отличным синтаксисом Haskell? "Я уже в Хопре!"

Comment: понимаю, щютка :\

Comment: Не очень понимаю, какой смысл вкладывается в понятия "качество синтаксиса" и "качество технологий". Кажется, что если вывести для себя набор некоторых стилистических правил, то Scala подойдет. А модель акторов, видимо представляющая "качество технологий" реализована в фреймворке Akka.

Comment: Простите за наивность, а чем вам мэйнстримные языки не угодили? Какая ваша реальная задача?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте Haskell + STM - для начала можно посмотреть [краткое руководство](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/advanced-haskell/beautiful-concurrency)

Comment: Или Cloud Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, вам хочется Scala + Akka.

Answer (score 1):

**Пару ссылочек для ознакомления**

http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/parallel/AFP08-notes.pdf

**Haskerl**

http://www.chalmers.se/sv/institutioner/cse/utbildning/Grundutbildning/kandidatprojekt/Sidor/haskell-erlang.aspx

http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~partain/haskerl.html

https://github.com/etnt/Haskerl

Answer (score -2):

Палю годноту http://pyos.github.io/dg/
Объединяет качество синтаксиса Haskell и качество технологии Erlang, превосходя оба этих языка по всем параметрам.

Comment: Осталось объяснить, что есть качество синтаксиса Haskrll и качество технологии Erlang. А так -- да. Java (в смысле ООП) кроет Haskell & без напряга.

     With Haskell's syntax but none of its type system

И на кой ляд такое чудо нужно? Исчо адын "выжрал васик"?